# Нельзя открыть программу «PyCharm CE», так как она не поддерживается этим компьютером Mac

Tags: python, pycharm

После открытия установочного файла PyCharm CE на Mac выходит данная выше ошибка. На маке установлено новейшее ПО: Sonoma 14.3.1. В чём может быть проблема?
Были попытки установить более ранние версии PyCharm CE, но всё тщетно.

Comment: `В чём может быть проблема?` - очевидно в том, что вы пытаетесь запустить блоб, который не предназначен для имеющейся у вас программно-аппаратной платформы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте
https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/pycharm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=mac&code=PCC
если у вас Intel
Или
https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/pycharm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=macM1&code=PCC
если у вас Apple Silicon

Comment: Благодарю. Ошиблась, скачав PyCharm для Intel.

Comment: auywea, Вам помогло?

Comment: да, помогло, спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за то, что Вы отметили мой ответ как верное решение. Если Вам не сложно, то пожалуйста поставьте голос +1 за мой ответ(стрелка в форме треугольника вверх).
Заранее благодарю и желаю Вам приятного использования и времяпрепровождения на чудесном языке Python!